# vue.js keyup.enter() to focus on next input not working

Tags: vue.js, input, keyup

guys

I'm trying to do the feature that when user press enter, it focus automatically to next input zone. Below was the code i wrote (basically i put `@keyup.enter="$event.target.nextSibling.focus()` to every `input` element, and i couldn't see why it didn't work.

```
<form
        id="formContact"
        action
        method="post"
        autocomplete="on"
        autocapitalize="on"
        ref="contactForm"
      >
        <div class="formContact-item fn">
          <label for="fn">*family name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="fn"
            id="fn"
            placeholder="please enter your family name"
            v-model="contactForm.fn"
            @keyup.enter="$event.target.nextSibling.focus()"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="formContact-item gn">
          <label for="fn">*given name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="gn"
            id="gn"
            placeholder="please enter your given name"
            v-model="contactForm.gn"
            @keyup.enter="$event.target.nextSibling.focus()"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="formContact-item email">
          <label for="email">*email:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="please enter your email address"
            v-model="contactForm.email"
            @keyup.enter="$event.target.nextSibling.focus()"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="formContact-item phone">
          <label for="phone">*Tel:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <input
            type="tel"
            name="phone"
            id="phone"
            placeholder="please enter your phone number"
            v-model="contactForm.phone"
            @keyup.enter="$event.target.nextSibling.focus()"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="formContact-item msg">
          <label for="msg">*messgae:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
          <textarea
            name="msg"
            id="msg"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="please leave your messgae here"
            v-model="contactForm.msg"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="formContact-item submit">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" @click.prevent="postUser" />
        </div>
      </form>
```

Also, is there an easy way of doing it, like if i can get all the input in a simple way (with ref maybe? but to all the input? Another option to use javascript query selector doesn't fit the purpose of using vue and you need to transfer the nodelist to array to do a loop?) Putting same code to each input like this doesn't look like the smartest way:)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your selector.

If you'll log `$event.target.nextSibling` the result will be `null`, that is because the input element is the last element in the div and has no next Sibling.
You have to select the `input` element of the `nextSibling` of the **`parenElement`**.

This should work perfect for you:

```
@keyup.enter="$event.target.parentElement.nextSibling.children[1].focus()"
```

(Consider to choose a better selector)

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between this property and nextSibling, is that nextSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while nextElementSibling returns the next sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).

So, please try using next **nextElementSibling** instead of nextSibling.

Comment: I've tried that at the first place before using .nextSibling. But no, it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I guess the reason why they were not working is that these input are not siblings, they are contained in different divs, in this case, Itried "@keyup.enter="`$event.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling.childNodes[2].focus()`", it still didn't work(tried to use `nextSibling`,not working).

Comment: Just noticed now your comment here... `childnodes` is also good but `input` is the `[1]` element as the index count starts from `0`..., success!